# Object detection based on CNN in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I want to build an object recognition system based on CNN. I collect a database and I want to apply the steps mentionned in the following example:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-using-faster-r-cnn-deep-learning.html

In this example, there is the code that aims to load the vehicule data :

data = load('fasterRCNNVehicleTrainingData.mat');
vehicleDataset = data.vehicleTrainingData;

I want to know how can I create these files for my dataset.

Thanks.